# Change client side configuration after nuxt build

Tags: nuxt.js

I’d like to know if it’s possible to change client side configuration AFTER nuxt build happened.
Scenario would be : build once, deploy on multiple envs with some configuration varations.

I’m well aware that you can affect some parameters with environnement variables (like API_URL), but it doesn’t seem to affect client side execution.

Example:

- Having axios.baseURL = api/v1 in nuxt.config.js
- nuxt build
- nuxt start
- Server and client side request go to api/v1
- Setting env variable API_URL= api/v2
- nuxt start (without rebuild)
- Server side request go to api/v2, client side request goes to api/V1. Expected behavior : Server and client side request go to api/v2
  What a I missing?

Thanks for your help !
Cédric

Answer (score 2):

You can use nuxt-env module 
https://github.com/samtgarson/nuxt-env

```
export default {
  computed: {
    testValue () { return this.$env.TEST_VALUE }
  }
}
```